# How to use logical AND operation on multiple pandas columns and change the value of column in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe with multiple columns as below:
[image]

How can I create a new column named as 'result' and perform logical operation like '&' on all the columns cells in a row to check if there is any single 'Fail' value present if yes 'result' column value should be 'Fail' else if in entire row is having only 'Pass' the 'result' column value for that row should be 'Pass'. Desired output should look like below:
[image]

Comment: don't post data as images, post it in a textual form fitted for testing

Comment: `df['Result'] = np.where(df.eq('Fail').any(axis=1),'Fail','Pass')`